# FB post: Image appears left next to the text instead above

Tags: image, facebook

I want to create an FB post with a text and an image.

I updated the tracking code with the `og:image:secure_url` and resized the image to 971x524.

[image: code example]

I cleared the cache and the cookies and also in the FB sharing debugger the post appears as it should with the image above the text.

I do not get it why it does not show properly when I do the post itself. Has anyone an idea what the problem could be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on factors like app type, whether it’s a normal share or an Open Graph story, etc. - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images